# Please recommend a good web designer/web developer web dictionary?

Tags: web-development, website-design

Please recommend a good web designer/web developer dictionary?

Answer (score 1):

[This one seems okay](http://www.abacus.ca/website-dictionary.php)

Comment: Thanks John, However, I was looking out website which can give a related keywords and their definition. for example : css media, web design snippet. etc all terms related to web design.